# Windows Live-Tile(printing images) doesn't work on my project

Tags: windows-10, live-tile

I develop a web application using Play Framework(Scala)2.7 and I try to set up a windows-live-tile configuration.
I wrote some meta tags below in `main.scala.html(path:root/app/views/)` and put images in `root/public/static/media/tile-icons/`.
however, I pinned my developing site(`localhost:9000/`) in Microsoft Edge but live-tile doesn't display the tile image. (Application name is displayed correctly.)

```html
main.scala.html:

<meta name="application-name" content="my home page"/>
<meta name="msapplication-square70x70logo" content="@routes.Assets.versioned("static/media/tile_icon/tiny.png")"/>
<meta name="msapplication-square150x150logo" content="@routes.Assets.versioned("static/media/tile_icon/square.png")"/>
<meta name="msapplication-wide310x150logo" content="@routes.Assets.versioned("static/media/tile_icon/wide.png")"/>
<meta name="msapplication-square310x310logo" content="@routes.Assets.versioned("static/media/tile_icon/large.png")"/>
```

[image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbzkq.png)

My sample web application project is started from the code:
`sbt new playframework/play-scala-seed.g8.`

Why doesn't it work and should I do？

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work well on local server. When it is raised to the web server, it seems to be worked.But I don't know why that.